# How to verify specific web element on different page in login module

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, data-driven

In my application when user login first time then on first page username is displayed (data driven approach using @factory). But if user logs out and log in again then a new pages comes with following text.

```
You're signed out now.
Click here to sign in again.
```

My question is how to check if this text -'Click Here' present then click on it and do same actions as mentioned in login function.

I tried to implement if-else block to check if this webelement is displayed then click on it and do same action as in login function. But it is giving error that

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using xpath=//a[@href='/Account/Login']
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Though I'm successfully able to achieve my result by specifying this element to click in Logout function. But when finally my test gets finished it always clicks on it.

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//a[@href='/Account/Login']")
WebElement clickHere;
```

//function to check

```
if (clickHere.isDisplayed())
      {   
          clickHere.click();
          username.sendKeys(strUsername);
          nextBtn.click();
          password.sendKeys(strPassword);
          loginButton.click();
          System.out.println("Successfully Logged");
      }
      else
          {

          username.sendKeys(strUsername);
          nextBtn.click();
          password.sendKeys(strPassword);
          loginButton.click();
          System.out.println("Successfully Logged");
          }
```

Please suggest a solution to check in login function everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clickHere.isDisplayed()` is giving `NoSuchElementException` as the element is not present on the UI on which you are trying to find it.
So, to solve your problem you can fetch the list of the element through pagefactory and then can find the size of that list, if the size is greater than 0, it means the element is present on the page else the element is not present.

You need to make the following changes in your code and it would work fine then:
You need to fetch the element list using:

```
@FindAllBy(xpath="//a[@href='/Account/Login']")
List<WebElement> clickHere;
```

And make the following changes in your code:

```
if (clickHere.size()>0){   
      clickHere.get(0).click();
      username.sendKeys(strUsername);
      nextBtn.click();
      password.sendKeys(strPassword);
      loginButton.click();
      System.out.println("Successfully Logged");
 }
 else{
      username.sendKeys(strUsername);
      nextBtn.click();
      password.sendKeys(strPassword);
      loginButton.click();
      System.out.println("Successfully Logged");
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I did same as you mentioned but after typing clickHere.  - it is not populating 'click' action.

Comment: @Samy yeah i made a little mistake in my code. Please try the updated code. It should work fine.

Comment: yes it is working fine now..but only problem is that it takes lot of time to start login first..may be because of implicit wait which I applied before starting my project...can we do something to start as in normal time interval.

Comment: @Samy The condition to check if the list size is great than 0 does take some time when the element is not present on the page because it first finds the element on the whole page and then wait for the implicit wait as well and then it sends that the list size is equal to 0. However it would work real fast when the element is present on the page. So there is nothing that we can do about it, you can decrease your implicit wait if your other elements are not getting affected.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `(clickHere.isDisplayed())` with below.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='/Account/Login']") ).size() != 0)
```

if you want to stick to your pagefactory then you can use the below approach

```
// below line will click on the "Click Here" link if only it's present
try {clickHere.click();}catch(Exception e) {}
username.sendKeys(strUsername);
nextBtn.click();
password.sendKeys(strPassword);
loginButton.click();
System.out.println("Successfully Logged");
```

if you would like to catch only `NoSuchElementPresent` exception you can update to catch only that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create BaseClass for you PageObject and impelent metchod **isElementOnPage**

Base class:

```
public class BasePage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    protected boolean isElementOnPage(WebElement webElement) {
        try {
            webElement.getTagName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your Class:

```
public class PageClass extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@href='/Account/Login']")
    private WebElement clickHere;

    public PageClass(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public PageClass YourMethod(){
        if(isElementOnPage(clickHere)){
            clickHere.click();
            // your logic here
        }else {
            // your logic here
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```